# Mixing Trained Neural Networks - Genetic Algorithm

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I have two Keras models, let's call them model1 and model2. Both models are a simple perceptron. Here is the code for setting up model1; model2 is identical.

```
model1 = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(100, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5, noise_shape=None, seed=None),
    keras.layers.Dense(26, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model1.compile(optimizer='sgd', 
               loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
               metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I want to mix these two models after training them, such that the resulting model is a random sampling of the weights and biases of model1 and model2. So for example, if the weights are represented by [x1,x2,x3,x4...] and [y1,y2,y3.y4...] the result will be a random combination of those [x1, y2, y3, x4...]

I've looked into merging layers of Keras, but do not see a clear way of accomplishing this in the API. I am looking for insight on how to build a new model that consists of a random ~50/50 split of the weights and biases of model1 and model2. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aight, after another week of beating my head against a table, I finally realized how much of a doofus I was being. Here's the function I made to solve this problem, and it is so unbelievably simple.

```
#Initialize and train model1 and model2, they are the inputs to this function.
def mateKerasNN(net1,net2):
    net1weights = net1.get_weights()
    net2weights = net2.get_weights()
    net3weights = net1.get_weights()
    for i in range(len(net1weights)):
        for j in range(len(net1weights[i])):
            net3weights[i][j] = random.choice([net1weights[i][j],net2weights[i][j]])

    return net3weights

model3weights = mateKerasNN(model1,model2)
model3.set_weights(model3weights)
```

Note, this actually randomizes each neuron's weights as a group. So neuron 1 with its 40 weights all move as one group into the new model, as do neurons 2 through 784. I will be building a version where all the weights are randomized, but this code is a good start.